# When you serialize and save an object in java, Where is the file created?

Tags: java, file, serialization, location

When you save an object in java (using serialize), where is the file created?

For example if you used this method http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0075.html

Comment: It is put wherever you put it.

Comment: (I guess he's thinking about relative paths...)

Comment: +1 for updating your question with the link.

Comment: The first part of your question before the comma isn't actually relevant. The question is just about what new FileOutputStream() does.

Comment: In case any one is looking for it: You can specify your directory in the string you are putting as the name of the file. Instead of "name.ser" you can call it with "C:\\name.ser" (or any other extension)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using the ObjectOutputStream for serialization and wrapping it around a FileOutputStream then the objects will go into that file.

For example (from the ObjectOutputStream Javadoc):

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("t.tmp");
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);

oos.writeInt(12345);
oos.writeObject("Today");
oos.writeObject(new Date());

oos.close();
```

This will create a file "t.tmp" in the working directory of the java application.

And about the working directory...
If you are using an IDE to launch your application then the working directory depends on where the IDE puts the compiled classes and how it runs your application.

You can use the following code to print the working directory:

```
File f = new File(".");
System.out.println(f.getAbsolutePath());
```

The "." represents the "current" directory.

Comment: Maybe an additional hint on *where* to find that working directory ;)

Comment: So it should be in the project folder, assuming it was created? Are there instances where the file is not created? Is the file hidden? When I use windows search to find the file, I only see the code containing the file.

Comment: "working directory" is typically the directory you're in when you run the program, if you run it from the command line.

Comment: Now I just need to figure out why the file is not being written.

Comment: @Andreas_D Why? You don't have to *find* it, you're *in* it already.

Comment: @rioneye if it isn't being written you will be getting an IOException that says why. More likely it *is* being written and you haven't found it yet.

Answer (score 3):

Generally wherever you saved it to.  How is the `File` created?

---

#### Update

From the link, it seems the code is creating a `File` by instantiating the file from a`String` representing the name, with no path.  Others have addressed that.

Instead, I would like to stress the following.  **Do not create files there.**  If they are temporary files, put them in the temp directory, as already mentioned in another answer.  If they are files the program might need to access later, put them in a stable & reproducible path, e.g. a sub-directory of `user.home`.

E.G. (pseudo-code, untested)

```
String name = "data.ser";
String[] pkgs = {"com", "our", "main"};
File f = new File(System.getProperty("user.home");
for (String pkg : pkgs) {
    f = new File(f, pkg);
}
f = new File(f, name);
...
```

Answer (score 1):

If you mean the standard serialization using java.io.Serializable, then there is no "standard" location. Your rather create an instance of ObjectOutputStream that decorates an aribtrary OutputStream.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
oos.writeObject(someObject);
oos.close();
```

In this example, the object was written in-memory. If you use a FileOutputStream, then you could serialize your object to an arbitrary file.

---

Edit:

In your link, the resulting file will be stored in the "current working directory" which is the directory from where you executed your Java app using the `java ...` command.

Comment: If I am using eclipse, then would the "current working directory" be the folder of the project I ran?

Comment: I am more experienced with NetBeans, but yes, I would assume it is the project folder, at the very top level.